# Continuous Touch in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

From my search, I found methods like `onUpdate-` and `onUpdateManager` but I must be doing it wrong because I can't find. I'm using `.runOnUpdateThread(Runabale);` but it doesn't work

If it helps, this is part of my code:

```
public class GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
private boolean action_up ,action_down;
Sprite eliSprite;
Runnable runabale=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UPDATE","OnUpdate");
        if (action_down){
            eliSprite.setY(eliSprite.getY()-10);
        }
    }
};
```

protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        Scene s = new Scene();

```
    PhysicsWorld mWorld =new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),true);
    eliSprite = new Sprite(400, 240, james_walking[3], getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final Sprite eliSprite2 = new  Sprite(400, 370, james_walking[0], getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    eliSprite.setScale(0.5f);
    eliSprite2.setScale(0.5f);

    FixtureDef characteristics= PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,0,.5f);
    final Body b= PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mWorld, eliSprite, BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody,characteristics);
    mWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(eliSprite,b));

    FixtureDef characteristics2= PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,.90f,1);
    final Body b2= PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mWorld,eliSprite2, BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody,characteristics2);
    mWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(eliSprite2,b2));


    s.attachChild(eliSprite);
    s.attachChild(eliSprite2);

    s.registerUpdateHandler(mWorld);
    s.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

    s.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            action_down = pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown();
            action_up = pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp();
            return true;
        }
    });
    this.getEngine().runOnUpdateThread(runabale);
    return s;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
    @Override
public void runOnUpdateThread(Runnable pRunnable) {
    super.runOnUpdateThread(pRunnable);
    if(action_down) {
        Log.d("UPDATE","ActionDown pressed");
        b.setTransform(b.getPosition().x,b.getPosition().y-10,0);

    }

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    Scene s = new Scene();

    PhysicsWorld mWorld =new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, 0),true);
    eliSprite = new AnimatedSprite(400,240,james_walking,getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    eliSprite.setScale(0.5f);
    eliSprite.animate(200,true);

    FixtureDef characteristics= PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,0,.5f);
    b= PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mWorld, eliSprite, BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody,characteristics);

    mWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(eliSprite,b));

    s.attachChild(eliSprite);
    s.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            action_down= pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown();
            return true;
        }
    });

    s.registerUpdateHandler(mWorld);
    s.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this for my game. Please adapt it for your code.

In your `onAreaTouched` or `onSceneTouchedEvent` of your scene:

```
@Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY){
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                leftPressed = true;
                //rightPressed = false;
            }   
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP){
                leftPressed = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

In `onManagedUpdate()` method of your sprite put:

```
@Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed){
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            if(leftPressed == true){
                playerCar.setPosition(playerCar.getX() - 4f, playerCar.getY());
            }
            if(rightPressed == true){
                playerCar.setPosition(playerCar.getX() + 4f, playerCar.getY());
            }

        }
```

This moves my sprite left as log as my buutons are pressed. So generaly you change boolean to true on TouchEvent == Action_Down and to false on Action_UP. `onManagedUpdate` moves your sprite when this boolean is true.

Comment: You are everywhere! Anyway now i have a continuous touch but strangely it just move once(althoe the logcat shows that the `eliSprite.setPosition(eliSprite.getX(),eliSprite.getY()-10f);`is performed everytime and when i realese the finger it goes back to where it was before. Why?

Comment: can you post your onmanagedupdate and onareatouched methods in original question post. for now we do not need anything else.

Comment: Thing is that we are moving sprite, if it is connected to body, we should move body instead. Sprite will follow.

Comment: But how is it possible to move the body in the sprite `onManagedUpdate`. I mean you need the body definiton which need the sprite definition which needs the body definition.......etc

Comment: incase of moving bodies you use:  `body.setTransform(x, y);`you can put it to the scene onManagedUdate thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71991/discussion-between-qera-hile-and-lukasz-motyczka).

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onAreaTouched` method of your sprite object and inside that is a best place to put your codes.

```
eliSprite = new Sprite(400, 240, james_walking[3], getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            setY(getY() - 10);
        }
    }
};
```

And you should register your sprite as a touch area listener.

```
s.registerTouchArea(eliSprite);
```

Note that if you want your codes to be executed until user finger is moving, you should use `TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE` instead.